# Bluetooth keyboard takes a long time to reconnect after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, 20.04

This began to happen after upgrading from 19.10 to 20.04.

After a short time where no keys are pressed on my Bluetooth keyboard, it disconnects automatically to conserve energy.

After upgrading to 20.04, when I press a key to wake the keyboard, it takes upwards of 10 seconds to get to a state where it can be used. In previous versions (and on Windows) this happens fairly instantaneously - at most a second or two.

Another thing:

Previously, keys I pressed while the keyboard was waking would *eventually* appear. So say my computer is locked - I could type my password and hit enter, knowing that it would unlock a short time after.

This no longer happens, and I now have to keep pressing the first key of my password until I see something appear.

In other words, the keys pressed between waking the keyboard and it being connected are dropped or lost.

I can only attribute this behaviour change to some change in drivers in 20.04, and would appreciate any help in reverting/configuring it so I can restore the "expected" behaviour, or an explanation as to why it's the new normal in 20.04.

Thanks.

One extra thing that may help:

I use a Bluetooth USB adapter. It has a light which is solid when nothing is connected and it pulses steadily when the keyboard is connected.
When I press a key to wake the keyboard, the light instantly starts to pulse, which would lead me to believe it's connecting okay, but not usable in Ubuntu for a length of time.

Comment: I have a similar problem with my Bluetooth headphones - takes long time to connect after upgrading to 20.04.

Comment: This is no longer a problem in 21.04. Behaviour on this release is how it was back in 19.10